# How can the order of widgets in tkinter be changed?

Tags: python, tkinter

How can the `on_change_order` method in the following script be implemented?

```py
import tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()

# Inserts labels 1 and 2 in sequence, using .pack() method
label1 = tk.Label(root, text="Label 1", bg="red", fg="white")
label1.pack(padx=5, pady=15, side=tk.LEFT)
label2 = tk.Label(root, text="Label 2", bg="green", fg="white")
label2.pack(padx=5, pady=20, side=tk.LEFT)

def on_change_order():
    """Swaps the .pack() order of the labels 1 and 2 appearing before the button."""
    pass  # How can this be done?

button = tk.Button(root, text='Change order', command=on_change_order)
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

When the app opens, *Label 1* appears first and *Label 2* appears second. However, when I click the "Change order" button, I would like the labels to switch positions. That is, I would like to have the callback `on_change_order` change something and then have *Label 2* appear first and Label 1 appear second.

In other words, how to you change the order of the elements of the "*packing list*" mentioned in https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/pack.html#M27 ?

Comment: It is easier to swap widgets using `grid()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your case, you can repack the required label before `button`:

```py
def on_change_order():
    """Swaps the .pack() order of the labels 1 and 2 appearing before the button."""
    if root.pack_slaves()[0] == label1:
        label1.pack(before=button)
    else:
        label2.pack(before=button)
```

However it is more easier to relocate widgets using `grid` manager.

Answer (score 0):

```
def on_change_order():
    label1.pack_forget()
    label2.pack_forget()
    label2.pack(padx=5, pady=10, side=tk.LEFT)
    label1.pack(padx=5, pady=10, side=tk.LEFT)
    button.pack(after=label1)
```

I think you are looking for this. Note that "Change order" button is not fixed. If you want it to save it's position on the right you should set it after label1

Comment: I don't quite understand the line `button.pack(after=label1)`. This needs to be done everytime `on_change_order` is called?

Comment: You didn't specify accurate position for this button. In your code it appears after last label, but if we swap labels button will appear somewhere else (on the top of frame, but I can't explain why). Setting it after label1 locates button righter than label1 as it was before you press button. If position of button is important you can't remove this line